# Connect to mySql on VPS server eventhough works locally

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, server

I have a React front-end, with a Node back-end to connect to mySql for data.  It works exactly how I want locally.  However, now that I'm moving it to a VPS server, I can't seem to get my configuration correct.

The error I get is: create:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. It's actually returning HTML, of the page that says it's can't find the page.

I setup an express server with this code:(I do realize I need to move login details to an ENV file... just haven't yet)

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql2');

const connection = mysql.createPool({
    host        : 'localhost:3306',
    user        : 'root',
    password    : 'xxxxx',
    database    : 'ppr'
});

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.get('/api/clients/all', function (req, res) {
    // Connecting to the database.
    connection.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

        // Executing the MySQL query (select all data from the 'clients' table).
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM clients", function (error, results) {
            // If some error occurs, we throw an error.
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            res.json(results);
        });
    });
});

// Starting our server.
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Listening on port http://localhost:3001');
});
```

I start this running on the server, and it runs. No errors.

But then my React app makes the first api call, and I get the error because it returns HTML instead of the data I'm expecting. Do I need to do something different to make it work in production?  I have proxy setup in my local machine which probably makes it work... but what do I change for production?

Here's the API call that works locally, but not on the server if it helps:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/api/clients/all')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
               this.setState({ clients: result });
               console.log(result);
            })
            .then(
               fetch(`/api/policy/all`)
               .then(res => res.json())
               .then((result) => {
                   this.setState({ policies: result });
                   console.log(result);
               })
            );
    }
```

Comment: Your backend listens on port 3001. On which port do you serve the frontend?

Comment: Front end is on 3000.